# Servlet, how to manage "per user" singleton accessors

Tags: java, servlets

I'm using a servlet and inside this i need to have an instance of object for each user, usually i would do it using a singleton but since (as far as I know) the servlet itself works as singleton i'm a bit confused:

how can I produce exactly one instance for each session/user?
how can I be sure it will be destroyed o session time-out?

what is the best approach, wait for some events of HttpServlet or act on requests accessing some property to understand what session is calling?

Edit:
The actual scenario is a web application that uses an external component for data access, isn't interesting what this object does for data retrieve, could be db accesses or web service calls i could ignore it.
What i have to create is an instance of this object for each Httpsession and ensure it will be destroyed after the session expire time.

Edit

Seems HttpSessionListener could be a solution: I could create my object associating it in a Map with the sessionid when the session is created and destroy on session expire. Anyone has experience on this?

Comment: what about threads?you tried ?

Comment: Sorry Ashes but i never used the word "threads" i'm talking about a session for each user-browser connecting my web app and the fact i need 1 and just 1 instance of my object for each session

Comment: maintaining one session id per user ?with session scope :per page/per browser/per app ?

Comment: No ashes, we are talking about create an instance of a specific class , let's call it Foo for each HTTPSession

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple case you can use `HttpSessionListener` as follows:

```
@WebListener
public class MySessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // new session created - add your singleton
        Foo f = new Foo();
        se.getSession().setAttribute("Foo", f);
        // if you need id you can use - se.getSession().getId();
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        // session destroyed - do cleanup
        Foo f = (Foo) se.getSession().getAttribute("Foo");
        f.destroy(); // your object cleanup method
    }
}
```

If you need to run it in the cluster with session replication, your class should be small and `Serializable`, otherwise you would need to implement your Map solution and `HttpSessionActivationListener` to restore its state on other JVM.

Comment: It's more or less what I already did, I created a singleton class that contains the map, on the session created i add the instance and i remove on session destroyed, I guess that since i'm using a singleton with map i don't need to implement other parts like the httpsessionactivationlistener, i just use the sessionid as key to maintain relations

Comment: @user1274347 You will need httpsessionactivationlistener if you are planing for session replication, since if session will be move to other JVM, there will be no your object instance for activated session in that JVM. Of course you can also initialize that instance lazy on first access.

Comment: yep, actually I currently create the instance just on first use and destroy it on session expires, it was a simplification to say i'm creating it on session creation. thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what are you doing, but the simplest way would be to create a client cookie for each started session.

The cookie itself can have an expiration period and you keep on the server track of each session where the key is the generated cookie.

Once the client has a cookie he keeps it using on each request in order to stay in the same session.

Of course you need a way for each user to log in and get his cookie assigned and some server logic to delete not used session ... etc.

Comment: I don't think cookies are a solution in my case, i need an instance of a specific class for each session. I addd some detail updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

In the description below, Blammy is the per session object name

1. During login or session creation, add a Blammy object to the session.  HttpServletRequest.getSession(false) will return null if there is no session.  This means you need to a) create a session and b) add Blammy to the new session.
2. Post login, check in the session for the Blammy object. If there is no Blammy, react appropriatedly
3. Use the Blammy object in the session as appropriate.

Comment: There's something i don't get: 1) how can be the case i'm acting without a session exists? we are talking about a servlet 2) how can act on session creation and session destroy?

Comment: Short answer:  read a servlet tutorial.  Session creation is not automatic.  Use an HttpSessionListener to react to session creation and session destroy event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpSessionEvent. On session create  add a session attribute with a constant key and your objects instance as value.